# Optional element based on enumeration value

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have an element `A` of type `AType` defined as an enumeration of strings like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="AType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then I have a complex type defined like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyComplexType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="A" type="AType"/>
        <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Actually, the element named `B` is present only if the element named `A` has value `"3"`. Is it possible to express such a boundary with XSD?